# Accessing user defined variables in JMeter "HTTP Request Defaults"

Tags: jmeter, environment-variables

I have a number of user defined variables configured in JMeter. I have an "HTTP Request Defaults" ConfigElement, and I want to use parameters for "Protocol", "Server Name or IP", and "Port Number".

I tried using `${__P(HTTP_SCHEME, https)}` as an example and it did not work properly - it always uses the "default" value provided.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) configured like:

[image]

you can refer the defined variable as `${HTTP_SCHEME}` where required, including [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults):

[image]

If you use `${__P(HTTP_SCHEME, https)}` it reads the value from JMeter **Property**, the property can be defined either in *user.properties*

```
HTTP_SCHEME=file
```

file or passed via `-J` command line argument

```
jmeter -JHTTP_SCHEME=http
```

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)